# Trying to turn fizzbuzz into a function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, fizzbuzz

I have only just started to learn python as my first language and whilst i worked out the code for fizzbuzz, i cannot for the life of me get it to do the items below. I also want it to print horizontally instead of vertically. Any help would be great (heads spinning).
Create a function which does this.
For example

```
fizzbuzz(20)
```

would print
    `1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz`

```
def fizzbuzz(n):

    for x in range (101):
        if x%3==0 and x%5==0:
            print("fizz buzz")
        elif x%3==0:
            print('fizz')
        elif x%5==0:
            print('buzz')
        else:
            print (x)    

def main():
  print(fizzbuzz(20))
```

Comment: 101 should be replaced with n + 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the items into a list. Then print the list at the end of function. You can join the items together with a comma in between using `', '.join(...)`.

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    result = []
    for x in range(1, n+1):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
            result.append("fizz buzz")
        elif x % 3 == 0:
            result.append('fizz')
        elif x % 5 == 0:
            result.append('buzz')
        else:
            result.append(str(x))
    return result

def main():
    print(', '.join(fizzbuzz(20)))

main()
```

---

It's good to also know that `print(..., end=', ')` would print "horizontally" with a comma and space at the end, and this would almost solve your problem except that the very last item would also have a comma and space at the end, which is not what you desire.

---

It's usually a good idea to (1) separate printing from computing, (2) make functions reusable. You often want to compute more frequently than print. In the future you may wish to pass the computation on to some other function before you print. So functions that immediate print are not as useful. So I recommend taking the print statements out of `fizzbuzz`.

You could return the string `', '.join(result)`, but how useful would that be? The list `result` might be (in the future) more useful for further processing, so I chose to return `result`. The printing I left for the `main` function.

Comment: should be `range(1, n+1)`

Comment: Instead of `if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:` you can use `if x % 15 == 0:`

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I was a long way off. After adding another ) at the end of the print line it was purrrrrrfect :). CHEERS

Comment: Would be perhaps more flexible to use `yield` instead of appending to a list

Answer (score 6):

Shorter yet:

```
for n in range(100):
    print("Fizz"*(not n % 3) + "Buzz"*(not n % 5) or n)
```

### Yes, but why?

To understand this, let's look at the parts separately.

```
"Fizz"*(not n % 3)
```

In Python, we can "multiply" strings, so `"a"*3` would result in `"aaa"`. You can also multiply a string with a boolean: `"a" * True` is `"a"`, whereas `"a" * False` is an empty string, `""`. That's what's happening to our `"Fizz`" here. When `n % 3 == 0` (ie. n is 3, 6, 9, ...), then `not n % 3` will be the same as `not 0`, which is `True`. Conversely, when `n` is 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, ... then `n % 3` will be either 1 or 2, and `not n % 3` will be false. In Other words, whenever n is divisible by 3, the term `"Fizz"*(not n % 3)` will multiply the string `"Fizz"` by True, and when it's not, it will multiply by False, resulting in an empty string.

The same logic applies to the next part, `"Buzz"*(not n % 5)`. It'll give us an empty string when `n` is not divisible by 5, and the string `"Buzz"` when it is.

Now we're adding those two things together:

```
"Fizz"*(not n % 3) + "Buzz"*(not n % 5)
```

When n is *neither* divisible by 3 nor 5, this will be adding two empty strings together (ie. `"" + ""`), which will of course give us another empty string. In that case, the whole print statement reads `print("" or n)`. Since an empty string is False-y, it will print our number n. If n is divisible by 3 (but not 5), this would be `print("Fizz" or n)`, and since `"Fizz"` is Truthy, it will just print that and omit the number.

### Bonus points

Or, if you really want to impress your interviewer,

```
for n in range(100):
    print("FizzBuzz"[n%-3&4:12&8-(n%-5&4)] or n)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def fizzbuzz(numbers, fizz, buzz):
    x = ['Fizzbuzz' if x % fizz == 0 and x % buzz == 0 else 'Fizz' if x % fizz == 0 else 'Buzz' if x % buzz == 0 else x for x in numbers]
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more elegant

```
def fizzbuzz(n):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        if not x % 15:
            yield 'fizz buzz'
        elif not x % 3:
            yield 'fizz'
        elif not x % 5:
            yield 'buzz'
        else:
            yield x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ','.join(fizzbuzz(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a novice coder so some of the answers I did not understand or it did not seems to directly apply to my problem. This answer incorporates Fizz_Buzz as a variable and the range of x is determined by the user. I looked at the above solutions and came up with this:

```
def Fizz_Buzz(x): 
     for x in range (0,x):      
        if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:           
            print('FizzBuzz')       
        elif x % 3 == 0:            
            print('Fizz')       
        elif x % 5 == 0:            
            print ('Buzz')      
        else:           
            print (x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `end=', '` to print in order to print on the same line, with whatever character you want separating the values.

```
class FizzBuzz:
    @staticmethod
    def fizz_buzz(n):
        if n % 15 == 0:
            return 'FizzBuzz'
        elif n % 3 == 0:
            return 'Fizz'
        elif n % 5 == 0:
            return 'Buzz'
        else:
            return str(n)

    def __str__(self, rng):
        [print(self.fizz_buzz(n), end=', ') for n in range(1, rng + 1)]
```

But it leaves `,` at the end. Instead:

```
    def __str__(self, rng):
        print(', '.join(self.fizz_buzz(n) for n in range(1, rng + 1)))
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 1):

one more :) just for fun :)

```
get_index = lambda i: bool(i%3)+2*bool(i%5) if i !=0 else 3
afb = lambda x: ('fizzbuzz','buzz', 'fizz', str(x))[get_index(x)]
fizzbuzz = lambda inpt: print(','.join([ afb(i) for i in inpt ]))
fizzbuzz(range(101))
```

> '0,1,2,fizz,4,buzz,fizz,7,8,fizz,buzz,11,fizz,13,14,fizzbuzz,16,17,fizz,19,buzz,fizz,22,23,fizz,buzz,26,fizz,28,29,fizzbuzz,31,32,fizz,34,buzz,fizz,37,38,fizz,buzz,41,fizz,43,44,fizzbuzz,46,47,fizz,49,buzz,fizz,52,53,fizz,buzz,56,fizz,58,59,fizzbuzz,61,62,fizz,64,buzz,fizz,67,68,fizz,buzz,71,fizz,73,74,fizzbuzz,76,77,fizz,79,buzz,fizz,82,83,fizz,buzz,86,fizz,88,89,fizzbuzz,91,92,fizz,94,buzz,fizz,97,98,fizz,buzz'

Answer (score 1):

i made a fizzbuzz that works for any number and words, so you can do fizzbuzzfuzz if you wanted. i made it in 6 lines (7 if you count the line that runs through the fizzfuzz)

```py
def f(n:int,m:list,w:list):
    s=''
    for x in m:
        if n%x==0:    s+=w[m.index(x)] 
    if s=='':  s=n
    return s
for i in range(1, 100 +1):  print(f(i,[3,5],['Fizz','Buzz']))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fizzBuzz(n):
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
            print("fizzbuzz")
        elif x % 3 == 0:
            print("fizz")
        elif x % 5 == 0:
            print("buzz")
        else:
            print(x)
print(fizzBuzz(50))
```

Comment: Why is this solution printing "None" at the end?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def fizzbuzz(num):
    if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
    return "Fizz Buzz"
    elif x % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    elif x % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    else:
        return x    

MAXNUM = 100
for x in range (MAXNUM):
    print fizzbuzz(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following works well (Python 3):

```
def fizzbuzz():
for i in range(1,101):
    print("Fizz"*(i%3==0)+"Buzz"*(i%5==0) or i)

print (fizzbuzz())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun one (obviously not the best for readability, but still kinda fun to think about list comprehensions):

```
def fizzBuzz():
    print(", ".join(["FizzBuzz" if x%15==0 else "Fizz" if x%3 == 0 else "Buzz" if x%5==0 else str(x) for x in range(1,101)]))
```

Don't forget, 3 and 5 are coprime! So you can check `x % 15` instead of `(x % 3 and x % 5)` for "FizzBuzz".

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one with list comprehension and Python3

```
def is_mod_zero(num, *div):
    return not [d for d in div if num % d is not 0]

def fizz_buzz(num):
    if is_mod_zero(num, 3, 5):
        return 'FizzBuzz'
    if is_mod_zero(num, 3):
        return 'Fizz'
    if is_mod_zero(num, 5):
        return 'Buzz'
    return num

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(100):
        print(fizz_buzz(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    a=1
    while a<101:print((a%3<1)*'Fizz'+(a%5<1)*'Buzz'or a);a+=1
```

it is verticle but very short %=mod it works as, if a%3>1 it will be the same as 1*fizz +0*buzz if a%3 and a %5>1 then it prints fizz+buzz else it prints a